# How to best untangle messages on multiple apple devices?

Tags: macos, iphone, backup, messages, data-recovery

Recently I’ve purchased a used MacBook Pro. Clean wipe, started with Mojave then moved to Catalina. The ‘Messages’ app wasn’t working at first. But I think I solved that by logging out of iCloud and then logging back in.

Now I’m trying to find some long lost messages (2017-2018) sent from my iPhone. They are not showing up on the phone or either Mac. Note: every device I’ve ever had as been set to: keep messages forever.

The old Mac has old messages but not new ones. The new Mac has new messages but not old ones. The phone has old and new messages but not everything and it’s also missing the ‘very important messages I can’t find anywhere but definitely did not delete’

1. I would like to not lose anything from now on.
2. Is it possible to recover messages from old backups or do they get rewritten/replaced?
3. Is it possible to have one device that is ‘the archive’ everything eventually downloads there and nothing gets deleted?